# Where did I fail with my basic iptables setup?

Tags: 13.04, server, firewall, iptables

I installed iptables on a VPS (Virtual Private Server from openVZ) - Linux 2.6.32-24-pve #1 SMP Fri Sep 13 07:29:30 CEST 2013 i686 GNU/Linux.

I also installed: `apt-get install iptables-persistent`

Iptables status:

```
iptables -L -v
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 96 packets, 4864 bytes) pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination    
Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes) pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 297 packets, 11296 bytes) pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

I used [these rules](https://gist.github.com/jirutka/3742890) to generate the files `rules.v4` as well as `rules.v6` in `/etc/iptables/`.

```
ls -lisah /etc/iptables/
insgesamt 32K
82101653 4,0K drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4,0K Feb 26 13:37 .
81218355 4,0K drwxr-xr-x 116 root root 4,0K Feb 26 13:37 ..
82100327 8,0K -rw-r--r--   1 root root 7,9K Feb 26 13:36 rules.v4
82101662 8,0K -rw-r--r--   1 root root 7,9K Feb 26 13:36 rules.v6
```

I rebooted the machine but same output from `iptables -L` as above.

I tried to `iptables-restore < /etc/iptables/rules.v4` as well for rules.v6 but I get this:

```
iptables-restore: line 154 failed
```

(at 'COMMIT')

Any ideas where I took the wrong turn?

Comment: Is UFW running?  It might be overwriting your changes on reboot.

Comment: No, no ufw package installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a memory allocation limit from a VPS provider therefore it wasn't possible to load iptable rules.

Answer (score 0):

Please execute below command after applying your rules in iptables.

```
$ sudo iptables-save
```

It will save your iptables rules.

Thanks & regards

Comment: Thanks and no. Why? Because there isn't anything usefull from my rulesets (neither rules.ipv4 nor rules.ipv6) in it like I mention above.